# Stop pre-installed screen recording apps from recording screen in android

Tags: android, flutter, screen-recording

I am using flutter and have disabled normal apps from recording the screen.
Here is the code

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE,
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
```

The problem is there are some phones where screen recordings apps are pre-installed and above code can't stop them from recording the screen.
So is there any other way to stop these apps from recording the screen?
On other answers I saw that this was not possible but there are some apps on playstore which successfully achieve this. So there must be a way.
I was thinking, as screen recording apps are drawn over , they might be detected through a piece of code hence we can show a pop up while screen recording app is drawn over.
Is it possible ? If yes how can we detect if the app is drawn over our app.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this code to my MainActivity.java solved the problem:

```
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (!this.setSecureSurfaceView()) {
        Log.e("MainActivity", "Could not secure the MainActivity!");
    }

}



private final boolean setSecureSurfaceView() {
    ViewGroup content = (ViewGroup) this.findViewById(android.R.id.content);
    //Intrinsics.checkExpressionValueIsNotNull(content, "content");
    if (!this.isNonEmptyContainer((View) content)) {
        return false;
    } else {
        View splashView = content.getChildAt(0);
        //Intrinsics.checkExpressionValueIsNotNull(splashView, "splashView");
        if (!this.isNonEmptyContainer(splashView)) {
            return false;
        } else {
            View flutterView = ((ViewGroup) splashView).getChildAt(0);
            //Intrinsics.checkExpressionValueIsNotNull(flutterView,          "flutterView");
            if (!this.isNonEmptyContainer(flutterView)) {
                return false;
            } else {
                View surfaceView = ((ViewGroup) flutterView).getChildAt(0);
                if (!(surfaceView instanceof SurfaceView)) {
                    return false;
                } else {
                    ((SurfaceView) surfaceView).setSecure(true);
                    this.getWindow().setFlags(8192, 8192);
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

}

    private final boolean isNonEmptyContainer(View view) {
        if (!(view instanceof ViewGroup)) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return ((ViewGroup) view).getChildCount() >= 1;
        }
}
```

Import the required things.

Comment: @Parashant Pandey could you please help me do the same code in native android app?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, there is no official way to universally prevent screen grabs/recordings.

This is because `FLAG_SECURE` just prevents capturing on [non-secure displays](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#FLAG_SECURE):

> Window flag: treat the content of the window as secure, preventing it from appearing in screenshots or from being viewed on non-secure displays.

But apps that have elevated permissions can create a **secure** virtual display and use screen mirroring to record your screen, which does not respect the *secure* flag.

Read [this article](https://wwws.nightwatchcybersecurity.com/2016/04/13/research-securing-android-applications-from-screen-capture) for more info:

> That would mean that an Android device casting to a DRM-protected display like a TV would always display sensitive screens, since the concept of secure really means “copyrighted”. For apps, Google forestalled this issue by preventing apps not signed by the system key from creating virtual “secure” displays

Regarding how some apps still manage to do it, you could try these:

- Check if there are any external/virtual displays connected, and hide/show your content based on that. see [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/display/DisplayManager#getDisplays())
- Don't show your content on rooted devices

Comment: hi I tried checking for virtual displays in flutter (android) through MethodChannel ,but couldn't find a proper way . Can you please guide me the proper code ? Thanks

Comment: I'm sorry. I am not familiar with flutter. There may be other posts on SO that can help you.