# How to detect if screen is being recorded in android

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I've tried `window.setflags(windowmanagerflags.secure, windowmanagerflags.secure)` it's working for some devices if we use screen recording software but if we start recording by built in Screen Recording feature (From shortcut menu) it allows screen record. I want to completely prevent recording of my app I've searched a lot but no success yet except [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63156931/stop-pre-installed-screen-recording-apps-from-recording-screen-in-android) answer provided in flutter i've tried in native but i didn't get the same view (SurfaceView). If this can be done in flutter then there must be a way in android too. Kindly guide.

Comment: "but if we start recording by built in Screen Recording feature (From shortcut menu) it allows screen record" -- what device are you testing on? If you use `FLAG_SECURE` properly, it should be blocking screen recording by all means.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks for your comment. It's not i've tested on OnePlus mobile which has built in Screen Record option that allows screen record.

Comment: @CommonsWare kindly go through the provided link you'll get more info.

Comment: "kindly go through the provided link you'll get more info" -- I am very familiar with `FLAG_SECURE`. What is the specific OnePlus device model that you are using?

Comment: @MuhammadAdeelShoukat any solution for your query. Is there any way to detect the running screen recording app and alert the user in our app?

Comment: @Srinivasan No. I ended up creating custom logic but that was not accurate as well.